# SCSS is not reacting consistently in my react project

Tags: reactjs, sass, material-ui

I am working on Material UI tables in React and trying to apply style to table cells using SCSS. As I have to apply style on individual cells separately, I am identifying the cells by their index position. I have imported and applied the SCSS correctly, and it is showing its effect on my React project. However, whenever I refresh the page, the style is gone.
To restore the style, I have to cut and paste the SCSS file import into the same file where it has been used.

My import looks like this:

```
import '../overviewInnerRow/OverviewInnerRow.scss';
```

My SCSS looks like this:

```
$innerTableBorder: 3px solid black;

.border-cell-bottom {
  border-bottom: $innerTableBorder;
}

.border-cell-top {
  border-top: $innerTableBorder;
}

.border-cell-right {
  border-right: $innerTableBorder;
}

.last-cell {
  border-top: $innerTableBorder;
}

.overview-table-hidden-row {
  display: none !important;
}

.border-cell-top-right-border-cell {
  border-top: $innerTableBorder;
  border-right: $innerTableBorder;
}

.border-cell-bottom-right-border-cell {
  border-bottom: $innerTableBorder;
  border-right: $innerTableBorder;
}
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to CSS rules. When the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) is equal, the collision is resolved by the css rule that is ordered last. This can get crazy in dynamic react apps.

From your description, it sounds like on refresh, the network requests are jumbled up in different orders. Learn your libraries specificity and design your rules to be more specific to avoid this in the future.

The easiest fix is to increase specificity by adding a wrapping class

```
.my-table-component {
  //insert your rules from above
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. As I had two components (outer row and inner row), I previously imported the innerrow css in the innerrow component itself. However, as I imported innerrow css in outer row component, it is working perfectly.